# Sources for learning about Scheme Macros: define-syntax and syntax-rules

Tags: macros, lisp, scheme, syntax-rules, define-syntax

I've read [JRM's Syntax-rules Primer](http://www.xs4all.nl/~hipster/lib/scheme/gauche/define-syntax-primer.txt) for the Merely Eccentric and it has helped me understand syntax-rules and how it's different from common-lisp's define-macro.  syntax-rules is only one way of implementing a syntax transformer within define-syntax.

I'm looking for two things, the first is more examples and explanations of syntax-rules and the second is good sources for learning the other ways of using define-syntax.  What resources do you recommend?

Comment: I have a similar question today: more examples and explanations of syntax-rules and good sources for learning to use define-syntax but many ressources mentioned in the original responses to this answer no longer exist today or are not easily accessible. Any further update responses to this question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your second question: `syntax-case` is the other form that goes inside `define-syntax`. Kent Dybvig is the primary proponent of `syntax-case`, and [he has a tutorial on using it [PDF].](https://web.archive.org/web/20170811221525/http://www.cs.uml.edu/%7Egiam/91.531/Textbooks/RKDybvig.pdf)

I also [read the PLT Scheme documentation](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/guide/syntax-case.html) on `syntax-case` for a few more examples, and to learn about the variation in implementation.

Comment: A recent `syntax-case` tutorial by Marc Nieper-Wißkirchen: [Extending a Language — Writing Powerful Macros in Scheme](https://github.com/mnieper/scheme-macros)

Answer (score 6):

The JRM Syntax-rules primer is quite good, but Chapter 36 of Programming Languages: Application and Interpretation, by Shriram Krishnamurti http://www.cs.brown.edu/~sk/Publications/Books/ProgLangs/) also has good coverage of writing Scheme macros.  That material has been used and improved over several short articles, tech reports, etc, over the past 10 years, so it's not a 'this was true about the X implementation of Scheme in 1983 that is no longer accessible' paper.

Answer (score 4):

The list of resources at [The Scheme Cookbook](https://web.archive.org/web/20150321052219/http://schemecookbook.org/Cookbook/GettingStartedMacros) is a great place to start.
If you prefer papers, then don't hessitate to visit [readscheme.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20160306064729/http://readscheme.org/).

Answer (score 3):

[Fear of Macros](https://www.greghendershott.com/fear-of-macros/) is a practical guide for using macros in Racket. It shows many ways of using `define-syntax`. The material may not be completely applicable to Scheme, but you might find some of the examples useful for knowing what can be done.